# How to change something in the _Layout.cshtml without returning View

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

I'm making a simple website and in the top section of the layout page in MVC I want to have quotes outputted everytime the page refreshes. I'm going to pull data from database and want to output it in the _Layout. But I haven't got the slightest idea of how to do it. And trying to google it didn't work.

ViewBag and ViewData wouldn't work for me, because I will have to set them up in every controller action I have..

So can you suggest something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if i understood realy what you are trying to do. But if you want to ouput something in your layout view., you can try to use child Action Method and you wil not have to call a method in each controller.
here is an example [Child Action Methods in ASP.NET MVC](http://theshravan.net/blog/child-action-methods-in-asp-net-mvc/)

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult GetNews(string category)
{
    var newsProvider = new NewsProvider();
    var news = newsProvider.GetNews(category);
    return PartialView(news);
}
```

Above child action method can be invoked  inside any view in the application using Html.RenderAction() or Html.Action() method.

```
@Html.Action("GetNews", "Home", new { category = "Sports"})
```

(or)

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("GetNews", "Home", new { category = "finance"}); }
```

Putting this code inside the _layout view make it available to all page that use that layout view.

Added on comment: You need a view in the Home folder (the controller folder) that have the same name with your method name.

Comment: I understand this but do I have to create a View for this Action? A view called GetNews ?

Comment: yes you need to create a view with the same name as the method name

Comment: I have just tried it and it says:The action 'GetQuote' is accessible only by a child request.

Apparently Childs can be called from within a View, not the Layout..

Comment: as mentioned as attribute [ChildActionOnly]. you can not access it directly from your browser. Just open any page that use your layout if that code is in layout layout, and the method should be executed and loaded to your layout where you have this code @Html.Action("action", "controller"). OR if you want to access that method from your browser remove this attribute " [ChildActionOnly]" from your action method.

Comment: I'm doing exactly what you say:

<body>
    <div class="container">
        @{Html.RenderAction("GetQuote", "Home");}
        <div class="row">

  
This code is in _Layout

I'm calling Home/Index and what I get is the browser saying Unable to connect like if there is no internet..

Comment: Solved it finally! I just had to return PartialView() instead of View :)